# Auto Increment to each cell in different section table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set a number to each cell in the table view, and i have diffent section so can't use `indexPath.row`.

Currently im using one variable `count` and increasing it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `count++`.

but it refresh when im scrolling table.

SO how to set auto increament number to each cell.

Comment: I don't understand your question, but it will come down to modifying the model data and forcing a table refresh.

Comment: use `indexPath.section` instead of `indexPath.row` for your `count` variable

Comment: Use `static` variable.

Comment: @MZubairShamshad it make same number to particular section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.. Will calculate previous sections and its row and adds with current row

```
NSInteger cellNumber = indexPath.row;
    for (int i =0; i<indexPath.section; i++) {
        cellNumber += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The instance variable won't work. Your index should be calculable, as your problem states, from the indexPath (row and section), lacally within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Try this:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    NSInteger count = 0;

    for (NSInteger sec=0; sec < indexPath.section; sec++) {

        NSInteger rows = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sec];
        count += rows;
    }

    count += indexPath.row + 1;

    NSLog(@"Current row is: %ld", (long)count);

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

copy and paste the code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                              reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

// Configure the cell...
NSInteger cellNumber = indexPath.row;
for (int i =0; i<indexPath.section; i++) {
    cellNumber += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)cellNumber];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It's basically the accepted answer with boiler-plate code around it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@(indexPath.section),@(indexPath.row)];
cell.tag = [string intValue];
```

You'll always get a unique number that you can use for reference.